# My rails 4.2.5 app server keeps connecting to production db instead of development db in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, production, dev-to-production

I'm running Rails 4.2.5 app on my local machine (OS X El Capitan).
It was working fine in development mode.

But then I decided to see how it works in production mode, so switched to production and run the server.

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rails s -e production
```

Not everything looked good. So I made some changes till all are working properly.

After that, I needed to add some features implemented, so switched back to development mode again and run the server.

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
bundle exec rails s
```

The server run without an issue, but I found that it was working with production db instead of development db.

I tried to clear all caches by executing `bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear` but it didn't help.

FYI, I'm using postgres for both production and development.

Here is the `database.yml` file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 30

development:
  <<: *default
  username: <%= ENV['OATV_POSTGRES_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['OATV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['OATV_POSTGRES_DATABASE_DEVELOPMENT'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  username: <%= ENV['OATV_POSTGRES_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['OATV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['OATV_POSTGRES_DATABASE_TEST'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Of course, I have set all the env vars on my local machine since I need to test in development, test and production mode.

What is the possible cause here?

Thanks for any answer in advance.

Comment: did you kill the previous daemonized production server?

Comment: @sixty4bit I'm sorry. I mistyped the text. I actually didn't run the production server as a daemon. Modified the question accordingly.

Comment: Check if RAILS_ENV is exported in your env. Maybe you did that as a convenience?

Comment: Solution: Restart your machine and try again. Also how did you know you were running on production database instead of in development? You have a production database in your local as well?

Comment: @Aleks I have a production db on my local machine.

Comment: Is there any way other than restart?

Comment: @MartinSvalin `echo $RAILS_ENV` returns empty string, that means development right?

Comment: Hm, can you try by running the `bundle exec rails s -e development`. Will it work then? (in case you don't want to restart)

Comment: @Aleks I already tried `bundle exec rails s -e development` to no avail.

Comment: @consigliere what about other things in my answer? does any of that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to write it here.
Possible solutions:

**1**.Restart the server (it should clear any unwanted variables which were
   set by production environment, and not cleared when running in
   development mode)
   E.g. `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>` was set by the production environment, but wasn't set by development mode

**2**.Change:

```
   development:
     <<: *default
```

to:

```
  development:
    <<: *default
    url: postgres:///db/database-name
```

So you would point to your local development database manually, instead of using already saved URL in production mode

**Or (maybe) third:**

**3**.Run `bundle exec rails s -e development`

Comment: Solution #2 worked for me, but not perfectly. I specified postgres url for development explicitly in database.yml and now it connects to development db, which is correct. But I have another issue. Rails console (`bundle exec rails c`) doesn't load `pry-rails`, it loads default irb. I have specified pry-rails in development group in the Gemfile.

Comment: Here is rails console logs: ```→ bundle exec rails c -e development
Running via Spring preloader in process 89518
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
irb(main):001:0>```

Comment: @consigliere heh, that is a bit different issue then connecting to a database, but to me it all comes down the same cause of the problem - some variables were set when production server was run and now those variables are not being set in development mode and it keeps acting in such manner (where solution #2 proves it). You are trying to patch it (but ok, if restart is out of the question). Try to run `bundle install -e development` or something like that (if that command is possible) and also try to run in terminal `source ~/.bashrc` to try to reload all variables again from that file.

Comment: looks like the root cause of the problem is `DATABASE_URL` env variable. My another rails app kept connecting to this `oatv_production` db instead of its real db even after machine restart. As soon as I remove the `DATABASE_URL` env var from my zsh and reloaded, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Is it normal behavior for Rails that it uses `DATABASE_URL` instead of `database.yml` if that env var is set?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. "`You can connect to the database by setting an environment variable ENV['DATABASE_URL'] or by using a configuration file called config/database.yml.`"  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html section `3.14`